# List.FindAll() shows error for null column values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, findall

```
objLst = objLst.FindAll(c => c.Emp_cod.Equals(string.Empty)
                || c.Emp_cod.Equals(null))
```

I am having a List of All Employees and New Employees who have been offered has emp_cod value null.

Now when i am trying to find New Employees using the above code it gives object reference error.

Emp_cod column is string defined as below when imported from SQL to DBML:

```
[Column(Storage = "_Emp_cod", DbType = "VarChar(10)")]
public string Emp_cod { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
objLst = objLst.Where(c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Emp_cod));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to call instance method `Equals` on null object. You need to check for null first and then check for string empty.

```
objLst = objLst.FindAll(c => c.Emp_cod != null && c.Emp_cod.Equals(string.Empty));
```

Or better if you may use [string.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) like Adrian's answer.

You may also try [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you want to check against, null, empty and white spaces, but only if you are using .Net 4.0 or higher

```
objLst = objLst.FindAll(c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Emp_code))
```